# Best way to create animated text in an iPad app?

Tags: animation, ios5

Anyone have any thoughts on how you might create an animated text effect within an app similar to this Ron Paul video?
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhxBM8ebECo

Just create an embedded video?  Core animation?

I get this is a fairly abstract question, but, just curious which direction I should start in.

Comment: Obama 2012! Haha joking, but let me see what I can do with some CALayers and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I didn't say I was voting for the guy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at that video, I see two independent elements in motion - the various animated text elements and the camera. Each can move independently (i.e. text element coming in place while the camera is zooming out, rotating and zooming on another portion). Depending on the complexity of the animation you are interested, Core Animation is an option, but for something like the video, I'd implement it in OpenGLES. You just need a mechanism to specify which elements move where on the timeline (XML, API, etc), do some calculations to put all these moments of the timeline in a whole and tween the animations. Not as hard as it sounds, really.  Depending on your needs, you can include bezier curves as animation paths (of both text elements or camera), but that can complicate things a little.

Embedding a video is also an option, but you lose the ability to dynamically create these impressive texts.